# Highcharts Combo Graph Overlapping eachother

Tags: javascript, asp.net, highcharts

I want to implement a Combo Graph with 
1. Pie Chart
2. Column 'Normal'
3. Spine

Now my problem is that if the column values are big, it overlaps the pie chart which does not make great viewing, I have a sample at [JS Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ykgNR/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Combination chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s;
                if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                    s = ''+
                        this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
                } else {
                    s = ''+
                        this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                style: {
                    left: '40px',
                    top: '8px',
                    color: 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [9, 9, 1, 3, 4]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'John',
            data: [2, 9, 5, 7, 6]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
        }, {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Average',
            data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                fillColor: 'white'
            }
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Total consumption',
            data: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                y: 13,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                y: 23,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                y: 19,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Joe's color
            }],
            center: [20, 80],
            size: 100,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

please give me some hint on how to solve this, one thing that comes to mind is set X range larger then max value of the column but not sure how to do that either.

Comment: I am using asp.net and this graph would be dynamic in nature, so I need a solution that is dynamic is nature.

Comment: ` yAxis: { max:40  // we will need to dynacially set this... Need more accurate way to do this}` if is use this it works fine, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set `maxPadding: 0.5` or some higher value, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ykgNR/1/

Comment: Thanks @Pawel this worked very well for me... great solution.

Comment: FYI I used 1 as it best suited my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use two separate charts.

one for pie and other one for combination of line and column.

is there any compulsion for you to display both combination chart and pie chart in same chart section?

Comment: Yes @strikers its a compulsion as client wants it that way, this the only thing stopping me from implementing it, the client loves it so I cannot do away with it.

Comment: then you can do only one thing set the max of the yAxis dynamically depending on the height occupied by pie chart

Comment: I understand that, but since values are dynamic... it could be bar graph of max 20 or in cases 2000 so how do I compute the max? any Ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: after you update the values dynamically you can set the max for yAxis relative to the space you need

Comment: I am looking for a factor which I can add to the max value, based on static content it comes to be 1.6 times the max values... but concerned if the same will apply in all cases... fingers crossed.